# SQL Joins and Relationships

Tags: join

I am confused by joins.  I want to know how to choose the join based on the relationship between tables, or do joins have no dependency on relationship?

1. if relationship is "one-to-one" then "Inner join" is the best.
2. if relationship is "one-to-many" then ?
3. if relationship is "many-to-one" then ?
4. if relationship is "many-to-many" then left join be the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of thinking about "type of join based relationship multiplicity" you should start thinking about the type of join based on **what you want to happen if there isn't a corresponding relationship**.  This is a much more useful place to start.

[See this post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) by Jeff Atwood.  As you can see in the sample results next to his queries, `inner joins` reduce the number of results and `outer joins` allow more results in comparison.  Both situations can be useful.

Generally speaking `inner joins` should be preferred to `outer joins` due to performance reasons, but the driving force for which type of join needs to be what you want to happen if there isn't a match.  Also in my experience there is a general preference for `left outer joins` over `right outer joins`.

As with anything in life there are caveats and gotchas, but this is a much better place to start.

Another useful visualization: [SQL joins are easy](http://www.halfgaar.net/sql-joins-are-easy)

[image: Visual SQL Joins by C.L. Mofat]